# K does not show function signature

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lsp

My full config is [on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/.dotfiles/tree/main/.config/nvim).

In my `lsp-config.lua` I have the following:

```
buf_set_keymap('n', 'K', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>', opts)
```

However, when I press `K` on the name of a function, nothing happens. Also, when I run `:map! K` I get:

> No mapping found

What am I doing wrong?

I want to know what the function signature on `NewGoFunction` is so that I can better understand what it expects.

**UPDATE**

I've just realised that some other key bindings aren't working either. For example I have:

```
buf_set_keymap('n', '[d', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>', opts)
```

But when I press that, I get:

> E388: Could not find definition

So it is trying to go to definition for some reason!

I'm really confused.

[image: screenshot of code]

**MORE INFO**

I am using `gopls` as the language server for LSP. Here is the output of `:LspInfo`

[image: output of :LspInfo]

Comment: What lsp-server are you using? Is it installed? Is it running when you open a file? (Check with `:LSPInfo`.) In other words, give a full repro (reproducible walkthrough) of your situation.

Comment: Good question, sorry I should have mentioned that. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/OYaIvGS.png). I'm using gopls.

Comment: Thanks. Add that screenshot to the original question, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for gopls server:

```
nvim_lsp.gopls.setup {
  cmd = {"gopls", "serve"},
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  settings = {
    gopls = {
      analyses = {
        unusedparams = true,
      },
      staticcheck = true,
    },
  },
}
```

In your lsp config, you had the following:

```
local servers = { 'clangd', 'rust_analyzer', 'pyright', 'tsserver', 'elmls' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

nvim_lsp.gopls.setup {
  cmd = {"gopls", "serve"},
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  settings = {
    gopls = {
      analyses = {
        unusedparams = true,
      },
      staticcheck = true,
    },
  },
}
```

Notice that you had a for loop for assigning `on_attach` and `capabilities` for all servers in the list/table `servers`.

But you forgot to add `gopls` to your `servers` list, so the `on_attach` (which contains the keymaps) wasn't assigned to the proper function.

Comment: It worked ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/EzLJF8U.png))! Can you please explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @J86 explanation added. For future ref, read the comments before/after you copy some code. Usually they're easy to understand and lets you know what this codeblock does and whether you need it.

Comment: I tried undoing the change and then adding `gopls` to the list of servers that I had. But that didn't work, in other words, things broke like they were before. I hypothesised that it may be because I was doing the setup of the `gopls` again, and the second setup block will override any previous setup. When I commented out the bottom block for `gopls` setup, it started working again. However, this means I now miss the `unusedparams = true` and the `staticcheck = true`

Comment: It turns out, I can just copy the `settings = {}` block into the servers for loop. All is good. Thanks very much @kadekai

Comment: Hmm, your assumption is probably correct (the second instantiation of gopls setup is resetting the first). I donno much about Lua to confirm it. But there should a better solution for this, something that appends instead of resets. Anyway, I'll remove the second method from my answer as it's wrong. Thanks for confirming.